# How to configure Python environment on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code

i want to configure python3.10 on kubuntu but only can run in terminal, when visual studio code try python can't run python3 from file .py, just using terminal, i want executing python from terminal of visual studio code using python3 fileName.py, what should i do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to save the file... press `ctrl + s`

Comment: What should you do? Provide details about what you have done so far, which results you have got and why you expect to get other results as what you have experienced. And add a Visual Studio tag as it seems that your question is closer related to Visual Studio than to Python. But ... maybe ... as alexpdev suggested ... you only need to save the file?

Comment: i found the error, it had to be with the routes, i can run my program..thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The label on the right is a small circle, indicating that you have not saved the file.

You can "ctrl+s" to save it, or the file read by the terminal was blank.

Comment: i found the error, it had to be with the routes, i can run my program..thanks

Comment: @alejandro padron vergara
You can present your solution as an answer for future partners who encounter similar problems.